# Multiple Cursors in Ace Editor

Tags: editor, ace-editor, text-cursor

Is there any option to add another cursor to my Ace editor?
Something like `var cur = new Cursor();`

I've been trying to search the Ace documentations for hours, but unfortunately I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Do you want to add a selection cursor, or a fake cursor for displaying another users position?

Comment: The second - I want to display another user

Answer (score 13):

you can use `addDynamicMarker` to display multiple cursors

```
var marker = {}
marker.cursors = [{row: 0, column: 10}]
marker.update = function(html, markerLayer, session, config) {
    var start = config.firstRow, end = config.lastRow;
    var cursors = this.cursors
    for (var i = 0; i < cursors.length; i++) {
        var pos = this.cursors[i];
        if (pos.row < start) {
            continue
        } else if (pos.row > end) {
            break
        } else {
            // compute cursor position on screen
            // this code is based on ace/layer/marker.js
            var screenPos = session.documentToScreenPosition(pos)

            var height = config.lineHeight;
            var width = config.characterWidth;
            var top = markerLayer.$getTop(screenPos.row, config);
            var left = markerLayer.$padding + screenPos.column * width;
            // can add any html here
            html.push(
                "<div class='MyCursorClass' style='",
                "height:", height, "px;",
                "top:", top, "px;",
                "left:", left, "px; width:", width, "px'></div>"
            );
        }
    }
}
marker.redraw = function() {
   this.session._signal("changeFrontMarker");
}
marker.addCursor = function() {
    // add to this cursors
    ....
    // trigger redraw
    marker.redraw()
}
marker.session = editor.session;
marker.session.addDynamicMarker(marker, true)
// call marker.session.removeMarker(marker.id) to remove it
// call marker.redraw after changing one of cursors
```

and add some css like this

```
.MyCursorClass {
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 2px solid gold;
}
```

for example of using addDynamicMarker see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/search_highlight.js

main code here is the update method, which is called every time ace renders. It gets array of strings named `html` and can add any html to it. Marker layer renders resulting html by doing `.innerHTML = html.join("")`

see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/layer/marker.js for more detail

Comment: Thank you, can you explain what the update method does and how does it work?

Comment: Added more info in the answer.

Comment: Years later... thanks for this answer! Just noticed an issue with the cursor position if `showGutter: true` – as the padding from ace doesn't update if shown. Add the following snippet just before calculating the `left` position and add to the line below when calculating the left offset: `var aceGutter = document.getElementsByClassName('ace_gutter')[0].offsetWidth;`